# Lightsaber combat trick

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

I read some of the posts here about lightsaber physics, but I never found an explanation to a question someone just asked me:

**When a lightsaber duel is happening, is it a useful tactic to turn off one's saber for a split second, allowing you to avoid certain obstacles (like the opposing saber)?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a recognised saber technique, described in [The Jedi Path : A Manual for Students of the Force](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force)) as [*'Trakata'*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tr%C3%A0kata) or '*Passing the Blade*'

[image]

As to why it's not used more commonly, the answer is that it's a risky (and highly advanced) technique that seems prone to failure.

The Star Wars [Wookieepedia page on Trakàta](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tr%C3%A0kata) describes a number of occasions on which it has been used. Note that all examples are from [non-canon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Canon) sources such as the EU novels and comics:

> Members of the New Jedi Order known to employ this technique include
> Jedi Master Mara Jade Skywalker. Jedi Master Corran Horn used a
> variant of this technique during the Yuuzhan Vong War, one notable
> occurrence being while he was battling Shedao Shai on Ithor. During
> the battle, Horn and Shai were locked in combat, and Horn deactivated
> his lightsaber, then reignited it into Shedao Shai, killing the
> temporary Supreme Commander.
>
> During her duel with Ben Skywalker,
> Sith apprentice Tahiri Veila used this technique to great effect.
> Skywalker forced her lightsaber aside, so Tahiri switched her
> lightsaber off and on so fast Skywalker barely had time to react,
> allowing her to extend the blade to where his throat had been just
> moments before

Comment: That's it, that's what I wanted. Will accept in 3 minutes.

Comment: I respect your knowledge about Star Wars.... wow